# ANSI Sql 2003 Lexing intervals

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

For my own interests I am writing an ANSI SQL Lexer. Specifically, I am trying to conform to ISO/IEC 9075-2:2003(E). I ran into a problem in the token stage with some ambiguity.

The lexical elements section define an interval string as follows:

```
<interval string> ::= <quote> <unquoted interval string> <quote>
<unquoted interval string> ::= [ <sign> ] { <year-month literal> | <day-time literal> }
<year-month literal> ::= <years value> [ <minus sign> <months value> ]  | <months value>
<years value> ::= <datetime value>
<months value> ::= <datetime value>
<datetime value> ::= <unsigned integer>
<unsigned integer> ::= <digit>...
<digit> ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Example:
'30'

Is the 30 a <years value> without the option  
or is it a  <months value>?

In theory I could write:
SELECT '30'

I created a YearsValue token and a MonthsValue token (classes). However, the ambiguity is an issue, it matches both.  I don't see anything specifically dealing with multiple matches in part 1 or part 2 of ISO/IEC 9075.

Can someone point out where in the spec this is handled or is it just assumed left to right?

Before anyone asks, I am doing this because I want to write a SQL lexer. Its not for school its just something to educate myself.  I don't want to use GOLD or ANTLR either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the 30 a <years value> without the option or is it a <months value>?

Based on my reading of a draft of SQL 2003, it is left ambiguous in a way that doesn't matter. Yes, the grammar does not specify whether the `1` in `INTERVAL '1' YEAR` is a `<years value>` or a `<months value>`, or even perhaps a `<days value>`, but it really does not matter. The description of how `YEAR` is interpreted is clear that `1` is a number of years, *even if it is parsed as a `<months value>`*. The standard says that the first component in the value is mapped to the first field type in the interval type:

> 5.3 <literal>
>
> General Rules
>
> 7) The *i*-th datetime component in a <datetime literal> or <interval literal> assigns the value of the datetime component to the *i*-th <primary datetime field> in the <datetime literal> or <interval literal>.

Comment: Perhaps I am not far enough along in the lexer.  At this point I am lexing delimiter tokens.  In section 5.2 the delimiter token may have an <interval string>  The <interval string> does not require a YEAR portion afterward. So, SELECT '30' will not be followed by YEAR.

Similarly, why is a <date string> not parsed into a <character string literal>.  In my lexer, I first check for a date match then fall to a more general <character string literal>.

Comment: @MRB `<year-month literal>` is used only in `<unquoted interval string>`, which is only used in an `<interval string>`, which is only used in `<interval literal>`, which requires a `<interval qualifier>`, which always includes the datetime field.

Comment: @MRB In `SELECT '30'`, `'30'` is simply a `<character string literal>`

Comment: Just found the <interval literal> production. So when building a lexer, should it just be a <character string literal> until a production tries to consume it?  Either is a delimiter so its moot from a lexer stand-point.  However, when I try to apply productions to the token stream I will have to do some massaging.

Comment: @MRB Basically, a `<date string>` is parsed as a `<date string>` when the context calls for a `<date string>`: the grammar as written requires a context-sensitive lexer. Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: Yes, it seems that what I need to do is parse to lower level tokens on the first pass (lexer) then when I apply productions I will convert to higher level (context aware) tokens.  I was thinking I would be able to parse to the tokens in section 5 lexical elements.